# SIGBART on [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I receive a sigbart error on this line in my code:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"ViewTwo"];
```

and this is the method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}

// Set up the fetched results controller.
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyData" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"ViewTwo"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But this is a strange error, because in the console don't give me any explanation about it, so I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Post the output you get in the console when the SIGBART happens, please.

Comment: the problem is this, there is no error in the console...

Comment: there is only write this (lldb) in blue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController needs a sort descriptor and a managed object context. You didn't provide a sort descriptor, so you'll have to give it that.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that there is no output for the SIGBART, try running the instruction (hitting step over see if it outputs.

What you need to do is check each element that you're sending to the method (by logging) it's probable one of them is actually nil or being dereferenced before the call executes.

Answer (score 0):

You may modified your xcdatamodled but did not re-install your app on device.

Just delete the app builded on your device and build it again, everything will be OK.

Here is what apple say:

abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

Typical reasons for an error here include:
 * The persistent store is not accessible;
 * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.

If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
 * Simply deleting the existing store:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]
```

- Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:

  ```
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
  ```

  Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.